# Ошибка в python pandas, "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"

Tags: python, оптимизация, pandas, dataframe

Прогоняю создание нового столбца в pandas  в цикле (12к значений). И выдает эту ошибку:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:189:
>
> **SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame**
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>     self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

Вот код:

```
for i in range (a):
    if T.loc[i]>0:
        t.loc[i]=T[i]/T1[i]
    else:
        t.loc[i]=0
```

Ошибку выдает, но в целом считает, но очень долго...подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: можете привести примеры входных и выходных данных?

Comment: залил на файлообменник, T, T1  исходные, t - выходные данные.
https://dropmefiles.com/0ab1l

Comment: судя по результату в столбце `t` - правильная формула `T1[i]/T[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [11]: df['t2'] = np.where(df['T'] > 0, df['T1']/df['T'], 0)
```

результат:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
            T      T1         t        t2
0         0.0   592.3  0.000000  0.000000
1         0.0  -633.0  0.000000  0.000000
2         0.0   262.8  0.000000  0.000000
3         0.0    -5.4  0.000000  0.000000
4         0.0     1.9  0.000000  0.000000
5         0.0     7.2  0.000000  0.000000
6         0.0   -37.7  0.000000  0.000000
7         0.0     3.3  0.000000  0.000000
8         0.0     6.2  0.000000  0.000000
9         0.0    -3.1  0.000000  0.000000
...       ...     ...       ...       ...
11971  4811.0  1136.0  0.236126  0.236126
11972  5370.0  1540.0  0.286778  0.286778
11973  5875.0  1730.0  0.294468  0.294468
11974  4754.0  1386.0  0.291544  0.291544
11975  5168.0   598.0  0.115712  0.115712
11976   362.3   174.2  0.480817  0.480817
11977   350.3    84.2  0.240365  0.240365
11978   356.8    54.6  0.153027  0.153027
11979   372.6    63.8  0.171229  0.171229
11980   446.8   119.0  0.266338  0.266338

[11981 rows x 4 columns]
```

проверка:

```
In [13]: np.allclose(df['t'], df['t2'])
Out[13]: True
```

замер скорости обработки:

```
In [14]: %timeit df['t2'] = np.where(df['T'] > 0, df['T1']/df['T'], 0)
1.14 ms ± 68.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
^^^^^^^
```