# Посчитать медиану списка по уникальным значениям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть исходный DF:

```
com x1
1   5
1   4
1   3
1   2
1   4
2   5
2   6
2   8
2   3
```

Нужно посчитать дельту x1, а потом от всех дельт всех медиану для каждой позиции из com - в примере только две.

то есть на выходе нужно получить нечто такое:

```
com x1  delta   median
1   5               -1
1   4      -1       -1
1   3      -1       -1
1   2      -1       -1
1   4       2       -1
2   5                1
2   6       1        1
2   8       2        1
2   3      -5        1
```

Пробовал через циклы, но опять же занимает очень много времени и выдает ошибку отсюда [Ошибка в python pandas, "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/937352/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-python-pandas-a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [24]: grp = df.groupby('com')

In [25]: df['delta'] = grp['x1'].diff()

In [26]: df['median'] = grp['delta'].transform('median')
```

Результат:

```
In [27]: df
Out[27]:
   com  x1  delta  median
0    1   5    NaN    -1.0
1    1   4   -1.0    -1.0
2    1   3   -1.0    -1.0
3    1   2   -1.0    -1.0
4    1   4    2.0    -1.0
5    2   5    NaN     1.0
6    2   6    1.0     1.0
7    2   8    2.0     1.0
8    2   3   -5.0     1.0
```

---

Если столбец `delta` нужен только для расчета медианного значения в группе, то можно все сделать за один шаг:

```
In [33]: df['median'] = df.groupby('com')['x1'].transform(lambda c: c.diff().median())

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   com  x1  median
0    1   5      -1
1    1   4      -1
2    1   3      -1
3    1   2      -1
4    1   4      -1
5    2   5       1
6    2   6       1
7    2   8       1
8    2   3       1
```

Comment: Лайк за преобразование в одну операцию. Я не додумался

Answer (score 2):

Очень [просто](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/stackoverflow-question-median-937665/blob/master/Answer.ipynb). Нужны 2 вещи: `rolling`, `groupby` и `map`. Итак...

Для начала, импортируем пандас и загрузим (распарсим Ваши данные):

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''1   5
1   4
1   3
1   2
1   4
2   5
2   6
2   8
2   3'''
data = [list(map(int, filter(lambda el: len(el) > 0, l.split(' ')))) for l in x.split('\n')]
```

Вот что получается:

```
[[1, 5], [1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 8], [2, 3]]
```

Инициализируем *DataFrame*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['com', 'x1'])
df
```

Результат:

[image: DataFrame example]

Используем `rolling`, чтобы посчитать дельту:

```
df['delta'] = df['x1'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0], raw=True)
```

Получаем следующее:

[image: delta]

В заключение, с помощью `map` заполним все значениия в колонке `median`:

```
df['median'] = df['com']
df['median'] = df['median'].map(df.groupby('com')['delta'].median().to_dict())
df
```

[image: Result]

Comment: кстати, загружать данные из вопросов на SO можно проще: сначала набираем в iPython/Jupyter: `df =  pd.read_clipboard()`, потом кладем в буфер обмена данные с именами столбцов из вопроса и нажимаем `Enter` ;)